# How to get table from value in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with names of other tables. How can I create a query that gets the table from the values?

For example, if my table has the values:

```
tables
------
users
users2
users3
```

I want to create Dynamic SQL function that knows how to take the values (i.e. the table names) from the reference table and then select * from that named value.

Comment: could you add an example of what your table-structure looks like?

Comment: Do you mean that you have something like oracle's `user_tables` dictionary table ? if so, why not just query it ? I.E. `select table_name from user_tables` ? or do you need dynamic sql ? hard to understand your question...

Comment: In a plsql function ? in a script ? there are many options, please elaborate your needs

Comment: i want to get this data with select, not pl/sql or script

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a one time script you can run the query:

```
select 'select * from ' || table_name || ';' cmd
from user_tables;
```

And then run the output